# How to convert english ti relevant tamil code(Bamini font) in C# using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have an object to form a pdf. I want to use the font Bamini while forming the pdf using itextsharp library. From the angular js part i will get the object in english characters. I want to convert it to the font Bamini which is a tamil font. Can anyone help me out with this. I tried the following and it did not work.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();

         sb.Append(printDetails[0].Address);

         //Path to our font
         string Bamini = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Bamini.TTF");
         //Register the font with iTextSharp
         iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(Bamini);

         //Create a new stylesheet
         iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
         //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
         ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Bamini Regular");

         //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
         ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

         //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
         List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(sb.ToString()), ST);

         return sb.ToString();
```

sb is still in english

Comment: You are using a version of iText that is older than iText 7. Tamil is not supported in those versions. If you want support for Tamil, you need at least [iText 7](http://itextpdf.com/itext7suite) as well as the [pdfCalligraph add-on](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) (there's an example in Tamil on that page). You can find a 19-page tutorial here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdfCalligraph_2017.pdf The examples are in Java, but it is easy to port them to C#. By the way: iTextSharp is now called iText for .NET.

Comment: On another note: you are using `HTMLWorker`. As many people have repeated hundreds and hundreds of times, on Stack Overflow, on the official web site, and on many other places, `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated. Since you have to upgrade to iText 7 to get Tamil support anyway, you should switch to using the [pdfHTML add-on](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML). I am also going to remove the angularjs tag because I have no idea how your question is related to AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks. And yes I was using itextsharp 5.7